# Restric a user to get or update a object made by specific user django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a task model like

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    made_by=models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

I have a view like

```
    def get(self, request, id):
        task = Tasks.objects.get(id=id)
        if task:
            serializer = TasksSerializer(task, many=False)
            return Response(success_response(serializer.data, "Contact Information."
 status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And a `PUT` in same way.  I want to check Only `User which made_by it can access it` . Is there any smart way to do this ? I dont want to query for check again in all views and hereafter.

Comment: Are you using authentication_classes in your views? If so, you could access `Tasks` related to `User`'s class by backreferencing it from `request.user.tasks.get`.

Comment: Also change `made_by=models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to `made_by=models.ForeignKey(User , related_name="tasks" , on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

Comment: @Rfroes87 yes I am using authentication , but dont want to check in every where Like it wont be DRY code . I want to do something like Decorator for this

Comment: Can you add your complete view class and serializer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried so many solution but At the End I made a decorator like this

```
def task_ownership_check(func):
    def wrapper(request,*args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['id'])
        try:
           task = Tasks.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        except Tasks.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(failure_response(data={}, msg='No task matching query found'),
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if args[0].user != task.todolist.for_user:
            return Response(failure_response(data={'error': 'You are not allowed to access this record'},
                                             msg='You are not allowed to access this record'),
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return func(args[0], kwargs['id'])

    return wrapper
```

So Now I can check easily by including @task_ownership_check  on any task

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you are using class-based views I would suggest that you override the `dispatch` method of your class. This class gets executed every time someone calls the view, no matter the method.

In this dispatch method you could first of all retrieve the task object like you do in the get-function in your current code. After that step you could then perform a check to see whether the `request.user` equals the object's `made_by`.

For example:

```
def dispatch(self, request, id):
    self.task = Tasks.objects.get(id=id)  # consider using get_object_or_404

    # Check if user is owner of task, otherwise throw a 404
    if request.user != self.task.made_by:
        raise Http404()

    # Will continue execution as normal, calling get() if a get-request was made
    # the variable self.task will be available in this function, so re-retrieving the
    # object is not necessary
    return super().dispatch(request, id)
```

Additionally I would also suggest using the default `LoginRequiredMixin` [(source)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to make sure that only logged-in users can access the view. It could eliminate custom written checks in many cases.

The `PermissionRequiredMixin` [(source)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin) is also a great choice when dealing with more general permissions that are not related to specific instances.

For more specific - customized - permissions you could also use the `UserPassesTestMixin` [(source)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) to write checks in dedicated test funcs to keep your code cleaner.

Comment: seems intresting , would check this in while .  so In case no need to add a decorator ?

Comment: @gamer I don't think using a decorator in this situation would be the best solution, though possible if you would really want to. Even though it is not always feasible or the best option, I would suggest to try to use the core Django features as much as possible. For example, you could also add a `login_required` decorater to the function (which is also a built-in Django feature), but personally I would advise against that since there is already a built-in mixin that does this whole process for you.

Comment: cant I return something like custom msg instead of  Http404

Comment: @gamer You can for sure! Simply replace the `raise Http404()` part with either a redirect or any other http response, such as rendering another template.

Comment: there is something fishy occured . I cant access user in dispatch fuction using jwt , its anon user and in PUT method its working fine

Answer (score 0):

a couple different ways to go about this but I think the easiest is to test the user's made by status. i.e.

```
    def run_task(self, request, id):
         if request.user.made_by == 'Foo Bar'
            . . . .
            return Response(success_response ...
         else
            return Response(failure_response ...
```

another, more complicated way would be to play around with the standard account model perms and set 'task' perms to false. i.e.

```
def has_task_perms(self):
    return False
```

and then in the process of user creation through whichever user type has the ability to give task perms. The most common way I am aware of to do this is to use an account manager (a whole rabbit whole in and of itself.) i.e.

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, password):
    # define regular creation process
    . . . 
    return user

def create_special_user(self, password):
    # define special creation process i.e.
    has_task_perms == True
    return user
```